# Cumulative sum grouped by year, month and day in a JSON object

Tags: json, postgresql, date, select, count

Let's say I have a table `orders` with the following rows:

```
ID      Cost     Date (timestamp)
1       100      2020-06-30 21:18:53.328386+00
2       45       2020-06-30 11:18:53.328386+00
3       200      2020-05-29 21:32:56.620174+00
4       20       2020-06-28 21:32:56.620174+00
```

And I need a query that returns exactly this:

```
Month       Year       Costs
5           2020       {"1": 0, "2": 0, ..., "29": 200, "30": 200, "31": 200}
6           2020       {"1": 0, "2": 0, ..., "28": 20, "29": 20, "30": 165}
```

Please note that the column `Costs` has to be a json with the key being the day in the month and the value being the cumulative sum of all previous days in that month.
I know this is probably not a task that postgres *should* be doing, but I'm just curious to see what is the solution to it (even if its not the most efficient in production environments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two levels of aggregation and `json_object_agg()`:

```
select date_month, date_year, json_object_agg(date_day, cnt) costs
from (
    select
        extract(month from date) date_month,
        extract(year from date) date_year,
        extract(day from date) date_day,
        sum(sum(cost)) over(
            partition by extract(month from date), extract(year from date)
            order by extract(day from date)
        ) cnt
    from mytable
    group by 1, 2, 3
) t
group by date_month, date_year
```

Comment: The results in the costs column have to be a cumulative sum of the previous days in that month (as I've pointed out in the question). Also, you have a typo in the second 'extract' :D

Comment: @InácioMattos: ok, I see. Fixed.

Comment: One more thing that should be edited is instead of `sum(count(*))` it should be `sum(sum(cost))`. Either way, you solved my problem, so thank you sir!